# What's the point of while (pthread_mutex_trylock(mutex))

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, memcached

I recently read the source code of [memcached](http://memcached.org/) , in the file `memcached.h`. I found this piece of code:

```
static inline int mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex)
{
    while (pthread_mutex_trylock(mutex));
    return 0;
}
```

I am just wondering why not just use `pthread_mutex_lock` directly. What's the advantage of the above code?

`sleep 1 or 2 seconds` after `pthread_mutex_trylock` looks more reasonable as it doesn't waste CPU resource.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I would ask that on [memcached forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/memcached) and I feel it is a bug (which might not matters in practice, because they got few contentions)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in essence a spinlock. The idea is to have the thread avoid blocking in the kernel, which can be an operation that hurts the efficiency of a thread.

This kind of spinlock would only make sense if locks has a rather low contention rate and/or were held for a very short period of time. Obviously, if you're spinning in the `while` loop for a bunch of iterations, that kills efficiency too.

Also, I believe that libc usually implements `pthread_mutex_lock()` with a little bit of spinning before blocking anyway, but I'd have to dig through the (probably difficult to read) source to verify that.

Another point - this would be very dumb code to run on a single core system, but those are becoming extinct.

Comment: Using spinlock in multi-core system make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can make another function wait for the resource to be unlocked. Which is also what pthread_mutex_lock does. However try_lock may be useful in preventing deadlock conditions, as in a priority-inversion situation.  Since the function returns an error instead of blocking the process (as pthread_mutex_lock does).

But I agree that this basically implements pthread_mutex_lock, with the difference that you can extend this custom function to prevent deadlock.

Edit:
If you add a sleep of a few seconds btw it can happen that the resource is claimed again since a few seconds is a relatively long time. By not adding sleeps you force the resource to be locked when possible, hence it's more fair compared to the wait.

Say we have 3 threads `B,C,D` waiting for the same resource locked by `A`
Assume we have a sleep of 1 second and an arrival time of `B,C,D` of respectively.
`0.1, 0.15, 0.2`
All three threads need the resource for 0.25 seconds (for simplicity) and `A` needs it for 0.1 second.
Then if every thread needs the resource every second we might end up with a situation where
`A` releases the resource at time `1.0`, then resource `B` can claim it at `1.1` and releases it at `0.35`, no other thread can claim it because they are waiting at this moment in time. Then resource `A` comes in a gain at time `1.9` and claims the resource again and releasing it at `2.0`. After which it is claimed by thread `B` again at time `2.1`. This ensures that only resource `A` and `B` can claim the resource. Hence, we get starvation of threads `C` and `D`.

Of course this is bad design, but you should abstract from the usage when writing a function to lock the resource. However, using random sleeps will fix this issue, but then again you need knowledge about the use of the resource.

Comment: The example is good. But how does try_lock could use for preventing deadlock? I know for priority-inversion problem, there is a PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT protocol which could boost the priority of the thread which currently hold the lock.

Comment: Well for example you can use this function for a thread that has high priority, so when the resource is released it is assigned to the high priority task immediately. Or with additional code you can check whether the resource is available and if not raise a flag that the resource should be released asap by the thread using it (if that thread has a lower priority). While with the normal `pthread_mutex_lock` this is not possible since it blocks. So basically you can come up with your own protocol using `pthread_mutex_try_lock`.